# Synchronize a program with semaphores

Tags: c, synchronization, semaphore

Together with a colleague, I have the task to synchronize a "handwritten" C program using semaphores. the task was to move `1` in an int[4] field round-robin with the other entries being `0`.

```
#include "workers.h"
#include "semaphores.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>





//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// global variables (all volatile!)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#define SIZE 4

volatile int ring[4];
volatile int von_position;
volatile int nach_position;
volatile semaphore semaphoren[4];
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// call text_setup() once before starting the test
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void test_setup(void) {
  printf("Test Setup\n");
for(int i= 0; i<4; i++){
  semaphoren[i] = sem_init(1);
}
von_position = 0;
nach_position = 1;
  readers=0; // maximal 1 (nicht veraendern!)
  writers=4; // maximal 19 
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// test_end() is called after all workers have finished
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void test_end(void) {
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        printf("%i ", ring[i]);
}

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// those 4 workers execute in parallel
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void writer(long my_id) {
for(int i =0; i<500; i++){
    sem_p(semaphoren[my_id]);
    printf("Writer %i :, %i>%i \n",(int) my_id, von_position, nach_position); // ***
    ring[von_position] = 0;
    ring[nach_position] = 1;
    sem_v(semaphoren[my_id]);
    if(von_position == 3){von_position = 0;}
    else von_position ++;
    if(nach_position == 3) {nach_position = 0;}
    else nach_position ++;

}

}

void reader(long my_id) {
}
```

That has been derived from an old *ring buffer* program given to us. It uses 4 "writer" processes.

Problem is that when finished, there is always a single one in the array, but in ca. 10 out of 500 runs we get intermediately output of the printf() (`***` in the code) like `3 > 0`, in the next line `0 < 2` or so.

Tried much, but no success, so far.

Hope I get a few good tips

Comment: Could you please elaborate what the output means and what you have done so far to find the problem - and what you actually expect? (Bitte arbeite aus, was die Ausgaben bedeuten, was du zur Lösung getan hast und was du eigentlich erwartest?)

Comment: the output in writer(...){...} first show the actuall writers id and then the old position where the 1 was before and the new position of 1 in the array.

Comment: at the end we get a correct array output like 1 0 0 0. but during the loop we get outputs like Writer 1 : 0 < 1 \n Writer 1 : 0 < 1 or Writer 1 : 0<1 \n Writer 1 : 2 < 3 as some examples which is obviously not the way it should work. We tried a lot but thats pretty useless if you just write shit in there after 6 hours cuz you have no real idea left^^

Comment: Pretty sure this program has race-conditions out the wazoo. `volatile` is not `atomic`.

Comment: and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The example code does not "move" a 1, instead it just stores 0's and 1's. My guess is that the threads are supposed move elements in a synchronized manner. Thread 0 moves from ring[0] to ring[1], thread 1 moves from ring[1] to ring[2], ... thread 3 moves from ring[3] to ring[0]. The threads can all read and all write in parallel, but synchronization is needed to prevent conflicts between reading and writing. Using 4 semaphores seems like a simple way to implement this.

Comment: Why 4 semaphores? Shouldn't there be a single semaphore? Otherwise you could still run into race conditions just as without semaphores.

Comment: Each thread would have a semaphore, used twice, first for when it's safe to read, second for when it's safe to write. I'm hoping the original poster can figure out how this would be implemented. Note that this goes along with the suggestion that each thread only reads from one location and only writes to one location.

Answer (score 0):

This program reads and writes concurrently to shared non-atomic variables. It thus exhibits *race conditions*, and its behavior is *undefined* according to the C-standard. Assuming you changed `volatile` to `_Atomic`, and exchanged all loads/stores to the atomic variables with `atomic_load_explicit(x, memory_order_seq_cst)/atomic_store_explicit(x, memory_order_seq_cst)`, your

```
void writer(long my_id)
{
  for(int i =0; i<500; i++)
  {
    sem_p(semaphoren[my_id]);
    printf("Writer %i :, %i>%i \n",(int) my_id, von_position, nach_position); 
    ring[von_position] = 0;
    ring[nach_position] = 1;
    sem_v(semaphoren[my_id]);
    if(von_position == 3){von_position = 0;}
    else von_position ++;
    if(nach_position == 3) {nach_position = 0;}
    else nach_position ++;
  }
}
```

could *still* be interrupted between the `sem_v()` and the first `if()`, between the `if()` and the `else`, and so forth. In particular, the first `writer()` can be interrupted *after* incrementing `von_position` (modulo 4), and *before* incrementing `nach_position`. Thus the next writer would see `von_position == nach_position`, and if *that* writer is interrupted in the same place, the next writer will see `von_position > nach_position`, and so forth.
Practically, you should move the `sem_v()` to the end of the loop.

Comment: thanks. We had it like that already. We just moved it around somehow to see what happens

Comment: so is my little problem caused by wrong synchronization? or just by variables not being atomic

Comment: @DanIel: without `_Atomic` (regardless of whether you've got `volatile`), the behavior is *undefined*. This is *always* to be considered a bug. *With* `_Atomic`, the behavior is defined, but not what you want. What I'd like to know is why you neglected to mention in your question that you intentionally broke the synchronization by moving `sem_v()`.

Comment: we didnt on purpose. We just tried around a bit and thats where we stopped cuz everything did the same